# Do I need to recompile user space program in new kernel

Tags: linux, compilation, crash

I am running linuxptp in Linux box with FC20. Now I move to Centos-7. Do I have to recompile linuxptp on Centos-7 before deploying it on Centos-7. The reason I've asked this question is we run linuxptp compiled on FC20 in Centos-7 and the Centos-7 box crashes. My boss told me to compile linuxptp in Centos-7 but I doubt it will help.
Thank you for your help.

Below is the screen shot of local console when it crashed.
[image]

CP

Comment: Without seeing the actual error message, we can't provide any helpful suggestions on what your problem might be.  In general, though, it's recommended to compile a program for each distro and distro version you want to use because different distros and versions contain different shared libraries that aren't necessarily compatible.

Comment: You almost certainly need to recompile the application on the target platform, i.e. CentOS 7.  Applications, in general, are not binary-portable between different Linux platforms.  Instead, the source code is portable.

Comment: I posted another question with the crash screenshot. Can you please review and let me know what you think:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64231034/why-does-linux-crash-when-it-runs-linuxptp-after-a-few-days